# How can I remove unnecessary information from IntelliJ Hibernate console?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

a bunch of unnecessary information is written in my console, such as:

```
21:43:21.835 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [increment] -> [org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator]
21:43:21.836 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [foreign] -> [org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator]
21:43:21.837 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [sequence-identity] -> [org.hibernate.id.SequenceIdentityGenerator]
21:43:21.837 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-sequence] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator]
```

how can i remove this?

Comment: You can turn off debug for `org.hibernate` e.g.
`log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info`